# Obter string de conexão local, trabalhando com (Azure Function)

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como passar uma string de conexão para minha `function`, 
esse é o `local.settings.json` que encontrei na documentação da ***Microsoft***

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "<language worker>",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<connection-string>",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "<connection-string>",
    "MyBindingConnection": "<binding-connection-string>"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "<sqlclient-connection-string>"
  }
}
```

Eu sei que assim :

```
var cnnString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");
```

consigo pegar a variável de ambiente do aplicativo no azure, como posso obter o mesmo resultado no meu `localhost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar informar essas strings de conexão no seu appsettings.Local.json ou configurá-las como variáveis de ambiente.

Para executar o seu código você pode definir o parâmetro de build no debug, basta clicar com o botão direito no seu projeto de start up e depois ir em priprieadades.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você também pode fazer isso por linha de comando, utilizando o `setx` se estiver utilizando o Windows Vista ou superior

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Local"
```